# iOS statusbar ignores supportedInterfaceOrientations in root controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, screen-orientation

I have an app that needs to be in portrait mode the whole time except when playing videos. In order to enable landscape mode for the VideoController in my project settings I've enabled all orientation modes as supported.
This however allows for my other controllers to rotate as well. In order to fix that I added the following to my root `UINavigationController`:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   if([[VideoPlaybackManager sharedManager] videoIsPlaying]) {
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
   }

   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    if([[VideoPlaybackManager sharedManager] videoIsPlaying]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Now I'm having two issues:

1. The normal screens of the applications respect the restriction and stay in portrait orientation. However the statusbar changes orientation regardless breaking the UI. I would have a landscape oriented statusbar on a portrait oriented screen if the device was turned in landscape mode. How can I fix this so that the statusbar stays in place?
2. I've set a preferred landscape orientation for when a video is playing. This is not working and the `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` doesn't seem to be called at all. Am I doing something wrong or what am I missing?

**UPDATE**
I fixed 1. by adding the following to my `AppDelegate`:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application   supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
    if([[VideoPlaybackManager sharedManager] videoIsPlaying]) {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
    }

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Problem number 2. however is still there. When I start a video it does not start in the landscape orientation. Any ideas for that?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try returning `NO` from `shouldAutorotate` when a video is not playing to stick your status bar orientation?

Comment: I just tried that and the statusbar doesn't seem to be affected by it - it changes orientation again.

Answer (score 0):

This code in AppDelegate.m will help

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
    UIViewController *topScreen = self.window.rootViewController;
    while (topScreen.presentedViewController) {
        topScreen = topScreen.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topScreen.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
}
```